# Code won't find my name

Tags: javascript

```
var text = "Hue, bla, hue, rhr, aek kmggg mlsd k Bjarni sdkrals fn lol Bjarni\
lelelele Bjarni";
var myName = "Bjarni";
var hits = [];
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++); {
    if (text[i] === "B"); {

        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length+i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(hits);
```

This is supposed to return my name, but it just returns an array containing a few `undefined` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (text[i] === "B"); {
```

Get rid of the semicolon. The semicolon in that point of the code makes it like:

```
if (text[i] === "B")
  ; // DO NOTHING AT ALL

{ // START A BLOCK
    for(var j = i; j < (myName.length+i); j++) {
        hits.push(text[j]);
    }
}
```

*edit* — oh and there's another one (with similar effects) after the `for` loop header. It should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just got a few syntactical errors and a missing break statement to fix. This should work:

```
var text = "Hue, bla, hue, rhr, aek kmggg mlsd k Bjarni sdkrals fn lol Bjarni\ lelelele Bjarni";
var myName = "Bjarni";
var hits = [];
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === "B") {

        for(var j = i; j < (myName.length+i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }

    break;
    }
}
console.log(hits);
```

To clarify; you had a semicolon after the line `if( text[i] === "B");`, another semicolon after your first `for loop` and you were missing a `break` statement, so it would've looped around  throughout the entire "text" string, which may or may not have been unintentional behaviour.